# AssertionError of different lists

Tags: python, unit-testing, enumerate

I made a reverse enumerate without the use of the reversed() function. I want the string and the numbers to be printed in reverse. However, when testing, I get an AssertionError stating that the lists do not match.

```
def my_own_enumerate(a):
    for i in range(len(a)-1, -1, -1):
        return i, a[i]

class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_own_enumerate(self):
        self.assertEqual([(0, "m"), (1, "e"), (2, "!")], list(my_own_enumerate("me!")))
```

Answer (score 0):

- `my_own_enumerate` is **meant** to return a *reversed* enumeration (as you stated yourself) so I'm not sure why you assert its output with a *non-reversed* enumeration.
- The loop in `my_own_enumerate` returns after the first iteration, so it will always return only the last character and its index. Instead, try

  ```
  def my_own_enumerate(a):
      return [(i, a[i]) for i in range(len(a) - 1, -1, -1)]
  ```

Then

```
print(my_own_enumerate('me!'))
# [(2, '!'), (1, 'e'), (0, 'm')]
```

And

```
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_my_own_enumerate(self):
        self.assertEqual([(2, '!'), (1, 'e'), (0, 'm')], my_own_enumerate("me!"))
```

Does not fail.